# Return MULTIPLE corresponding values for one Lookup Value at a time and different ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm new in this forum and in vba language so i'm hoping for some guidance. I have a workbook with different sheets but right now there are only 3 that matter. The first and thrid sheet have data that will be interconnected in the Sheet2. 
In Sheet1 and Sheet3 I have [Sheet1_Sheet3_Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjLoV.png). And this is Sheet 2 [Sheet2_Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fAzo.png) which is, in a first fase all empty and I want to automatize it since i was doing this work manually before. In the image is what I need to get. So far I have the following code, which works and fills column C of Sheet2. 
But i'm having problems with Column A. I was trying to simply use a formula like:

```
{=IF(A3=A2;INDEX(Sheet3!$A$3:$A$16;SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$B$3;Sheet3!$C$3:$C$16));MATCH(ROW(Sheet3!$C$3:$C$16);ROW(Sheet3!$C$3:$C$16)));ROW(A1)));INDEX(Sheet3!$A3:$A$16;SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet1!$B3;Sheet3!$C$3:$C$16));MATCH(ROW(Sheet3!$C$3:$C$16);ROW(Sheet3!$C$3:$C$16)));ROW(A$1))))}
```

The problem is I get an error when the text in column C changes and right now I'm stuck. I don't know if it will be better to develop another macro or if there is something I can change in the formula.

I'm sorry if it is difficult to understand what I'm asking but it is kind of hard to explain it.
I need to go throught every row in sheet1, so for example: in Sheet 1 I have in row 3, INST - I_1 and ID - AA. The formula searches for AA on sheet3 and returns all values in order and fills column A in sheet 2. Then it will go to row 4 in sheet 1 again and repeat the process once again until there are no more values on Sheet1.

```
Sub TestSheet2()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range

    xTitleId = "Sheet1"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    On Error Resume Next
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Select:", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)

    xTitleId = "Sheet2"

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Select:", xTitleId, Type:=8)
    Set OutRng = OutRng.Range("A1")

    For Each Rng In InputRng.Rows
        xValue = Rng.Range("A1").Value
        xNum = Rng.Range("C1").Value

        OutRng.Resize(xNum, 1).Value = xValue

        Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(xNum, 0)

    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: is `InputBox` really needed?

Comment: It is just to make it easier for me. In reality I have more than 2000 values on sheet 1 and I can't go through them all at once.

Comment: re: *' and I can't go through them all at once.'* - Why not? Memory array processing might make short work of this.

Comment: Hum...actually you two are right. I don't need it. Like I said I'm new to this and I have a macro similar to this one in a previous sheet but because I need to input values manually. In this 3 sheets I don't need it, I just need to discriminate the information that already exists.
Thanks, I will change that!!But I still have the problem with column A. Still trying to solve it but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the images provided, I was able to loop through a couple of arrays and come up with this.

```
Sub fill_er_up()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long
    Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2() As Variant, arr3 As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
            .Cells.Sort key1:=.Columns(2), order1:=xlAscending, _
                        key2:=.Columns(1), order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
            arr1 = .Cells.Value2
        End With
    End With

    With Worksheets("sheet3")
        With .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
            .Cells.Sort key1:=.Columns(3), order1:=xlAscending, _
                        key2:=.Columns(1), order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
            arr3 = .Cells.Value2
        End With
    End With

    For a = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
        For c = LBound(arr3, 1) To UBound(arr3, 1)
            'Do While arr3(c, 3) <> arr1(a, 2): c = c + 1: Loop
            If arr3(c, 3) = arr1(a, 2) Then
                b = b + 1
                ReDim Preserve arr2(1 To 3, 1 To b)
                arr2(1, b) = arr3(c, 1)
                arr2(2, b) = arr3(c, 3)
                arr2(3, b) = arr1(a, 1)
            End If
        Next c
    Next a

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        Dim arr4 As Variant
        arr4 = my_2D_Transpose(arr4, arr2)
        .Cells(3, 1).Resize(UBound(arr4, 1), UBound(arr4, 2)) = arr4
    End With

    Erase arr1: Erase arr2: Erase arr3: Erase arr4

End Sub

Function my_2D_Transpose(a1 As Variant, a2 As Variant)
    Dim a As Long, b As Long
    ReDim a1(1 To UBound(a2, 2), 1 To UBound(a2, 1))
    For a = LBound(a2, 1) To UBound(a2, 1)
        For b = LBound(a2, 2) To UBound(a2, 2)
            a1(b, a) = Trim(a2(a, b))
        Next b
    Next a
    my_2D_Transpose = a1
End Function
```

I added in the id to the second column of the results in sheet2. It seemed a reasonable way to fill blank cells.

[image: conf_id_inst]

Comment: I was not expecting to get this kind of help. Wow...really appreciate this. Your code worked like a charm. I didn't put any information on column B because in my real workbook, that column has a VLOOKUP function which searches values in another worksheet according to column A. Since it was basic and I wanted to make myself the clearest as possible, as what the range of my problem really was I didn't add that information. So it's my fault on that! But this is really great because now I can adapt your code to match that. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate your results table with the code below, filtering the range on `Sheet3`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeIDs()
    Dim instSh As Worksheet
    Dim compfSh As Worksheet
    Dim mergeSh As Worksheet
    Dim inst As Range
    Dim compf As Range
    Dim merge As Range
    Dim lastInst As Long
    Dim lastCompf As Long
    Dim allCompf As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim mergeRow As Long

    '--- initialize ranges
    Set instSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set compfSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set mergeSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set inst = instSh.Range("A3")
    Set compf = compfSh.Range("A2")
    Set merge = mergeSh.Range("A3")
    lastInst = instSh.Cells(instSh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    allCompf = compfSh.Cells(compfSh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    '--- clear destination
    mergeSh.Range("A:C").ClearContents
    merge.Cells(0, 1).Value = "COMPF"
    merge.Cells(0, 3).Value = "INST"

    '--- loop and build...
    mergeRow = 1
    For i = 1 To (lastInst - inst.Row + 1)
        '--- set the compf range to autofilter
        compfSh.AutoFilterMode = False
        compf.Resize(allCompf - compf.Row, 3).AutoFilter
        compf.Resize(allCompf - compf.Row, 3).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=inst.Cells(i, 2).Value
        '--- merge the filtered values with the inst value
        lastCompf = compfSh.Cells(compfSh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 1 To (lastCompf - compf.Row)
            merge.Cells(mergeRow, 1).Value = compf.Cells(j + 1, 1).Value
            merge.Cells(mergeRow, 3).Value = inst.Cells(i, 1).Value
            mergeRow = mergeRow + 1
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Really, really appreciate your help. I was testing your code and I realized that I didn't explain myself properly. I see that for each INST on sheet1 the code searches on Sheet3 the corresponding range on column A and the one before. This is, nonetheless, really helpful and since I'm kinda of new in this it is really great to be able to study through your help. I was not expecting to get this kind of help. Really grateful!